# What is the code for selecting a Telerik radiobutton?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

What code should I write to select a Telerik radiobutton?

It doesn't have a .checked property.

Comment: How are you using the controls?  Is this an ASP.NET page or a Windows form? (should have asked this before I retagged your question).  If you can provide some context for what you're trying to accomplish that will help people to better understand and answer your question. :)

Answer (score 2):

try `.ToggleState`

Answer (score 1):

```
RadRadioButton1.ToggleState = Telerik.WinControls.Enumerations.ToggleState.Off
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the which RadRadioButton was selected use `radbtn.SelectedItem.Value`

To set the RadRadioButton use `radbtn.Items.FindByValue("1").Selected = true`